# How can I fix this "Expected ',' separator? Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

When I put this in my code, it says "Expected '.' separator. Help?

```
 func RandomInt(#min: 300, max: 800) -> Int {
        if max < min { return min }
        return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32((max - min) + 1))) + min
    }
```

Comment: You seem to be passing values (`300` and `800`) in a function definition instead of specifying the types of the `min` and `max` parameters. What are you trying to do here? Are those meant to be default values?

Answer (score 3):

Message from swift 2.0: *# has been removed from Swift...*

So, I wrote your method at below, with default `min` is 300, default `max` is 800

```
func randomInt(min min: Int=300, max: Int=800) -> Int {
    if max < min { return min }
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32((max - min) + 1))) + min
}
```

If your want to use this method with default value, call:

```
let random = randomInt()
```

or set `min`, `max` to get random value:

```
let random = randomInt(min:1, max:10)
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Jonah said, you should write:

```
func RandomInt(#min: Int, max: Int) -> Int {
    if max < min { return min }
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32((max - min) + 1))) + min
}
```

And then call this function using

```
randomInteger = RandomInt(min: 300, max: 800)
```

Is this what you were looking for?